# Subtask is disappear after applied grouping in SharePoint task list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I've created subtasks to a task and it shows like
[image]

And when I applied grouping, sub-tasks are no more sub task and become a individual task like
[image]

I just want to show sub-tasks as first image even after apply grouping, How to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately , you can't show `multi-level task structure` with custom views that have a grouping or sorting or filter.

So in this case, you should not try to customize the default view that shows task structure , and prepares a new custom view with your (Grouping) requirements.

Meanwhile , There's a workaround that may help you:

- In your tasks list , add a new column as `Parent task ID`, and update the subtasks with its related `Parent task ID` then group by this field in your view.